# Creating a chart when the data has gaps and the x-axis is not continue

Tags: excel

I want to create a line chart from a table where I do no have all the data.
Moreover, I need that the x-axis uses the values in the first row, which are not continue. This table shows a short part of the whole data:

[image: table]

The first row is the x-axis and the remaining rows correspond to the lines in the chart.

How should I proceed in order to ignore the gaps, and each line was drawn taking only into account the available data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore gaps and create a continuous line

Right Click Chart > Click 'Hidden and Empty Cells' > Select Option 'Connect Data points with line'